# Protecting my code if I supply the Computer

Tags: decompiling

I know this type of question has been done to death.

My question relates to protecting my code that is installed on a clients PC.

I know the answers are to obfuscate, get a patent, put code on my server, accept it will be hacked, consider that my code is not THAT important or unique etc..

BUT, I am supplying the Windows PC to the client(s) with my software pre-installed.

It is a C# .Net app.

Under these circumstances where I am supplying the hardware is there any other 'tricks' I can use to prevent decompilation my code?

Thanks

Comment: At rest encryption of the hard disk + user for client with limited privileges. Don't share admin user's password with client.

Comment: interesting approach.  Encryption I mean.  Do you have any info regarding that? However, I will obviously Google that. Thanks

Comment: @AndrewSimpson - this will prevent casual theft, but nothing prevents the user from booting the PC with another OS and grabbing the C# assembly off the hard disk for further analysis.

Comment: @DavidChing At rest encryption prevents that :)

Comment: @DavidChing Hi, I know you could use a linux boot to do that.  I need to investigate this 'rest encryption'.

Comment: @AndrewSimpson at rest encryption is something that would typically be built into the operating system. For example OSX comes with FileVault. Not sure what the windows offering is but I believe it's available.

Comment: @Asaph Thanks, I Googling as I type :)

Comment: @AndrewSimpson Looks like the windows flavor of at rest encryption is called "BitLocker". Google that.

Comment: @Asaph excellent. I seem to remember that name for the DOS days. You  posted all your comments as an answer but took it down. I was going to accept..

Comment: @AndrewSimpson: Ok I'll restore the answer.

Comment: That's only useful if the user can't get in any other way. For someone with physical hardware access, that's rarely the case: If they can open the box and install a PCI card, they can get full bus access, which means they can trivially read all of RAM, including not only your code but the hard drive's encryption keys as well.

Comment: Granted, those cards are somewhat expensive, but so is reverse engineer time: If you're worried about someone reverse-engineering a nontrivial project, your risk profile already includes an attacker with a very substantial budget.

Comment: (If you're only worried about attackers on the cheap, then why are you bothering with countermeasures at all? Getting code stolen via reverse-engineering into a maintainable/supportable state for commercial use is a very, very expensive proposition)

Comment: This question would be a better fit for http://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @CharlesDuffy These are fair points. Would you then agree that BitLocker + user account with limited privileges substantially raises the bar for attack making it impractical for the vast majority of potential attackers?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy you have given me much to think about. I have tried Obfusicators but DotPeek seems to have no problem reading it back

Comment: @Asaph, depends on what you're considering a "potential attacker" in the first case. If you're looking at professional reverse engineers, vs your average second-year CSCI student, that's a very different profile.

Comment: @closer -  off topic -  point taken. Where else can I post this?

Comment: @closer - to broad - why?  So far there has been 1 type of answer?

Comment: @closers When I posted this question I was anticipating a code answer. The answers given so far I had not considered..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [BitLocker](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/bitlocker) (at rest encryption) on the hard disk and a user for your client with limited privileges. Don't share the admin user's password with your client.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Do you mean encryption keys? I propose leaving key management to the OS (BitLocker).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Hi, I was going to use a universal key.  I know that is a risk  but it would require no mamagement

Comment: @chaps thought you meant the Admin Password

Comment: @Asaph, that would be workable when using TPM hardware -- not otherwise.

Comment: I accepted  the answer because I had not consider this type of answer AND it offers another layer of protection for the cheap hacker..